My rubber plant is struggling with small new growths and yellowing leaves. What am I doing wrong?


I’ve had the plant for 6 months. It is placed by a window with indirect light, and I water it once a week with 24 oz of water, with some water draining out the bottom. It was repotted 3 months ago.

Since then, it has had two new growths. The first was healthy and the same size as the older leaves, but the second is extremely small (about 30% of the size; see picture #3). Also, yesterday, I found one fallen yellow leaf (picture #2) and another about to fall (see picture #1).


I'd appreciate any advice on how to improve its care. Thank you.

For how long has the plant been getting sunlight and was the plant fertilized or not?

Thank you! I use fertilizer during one or two waterings last 6 months. It is in direct sunlight most of the time, but there was a 1 week period very recently it could have received a bit more b/c I kept the empty window (no blinds obstruction) when traveling for a week, and the weather was very sunny during that time. The leaves that are yellowing are bottom ones tho (not the top ones which would be most exposed to sun?)
